# How to send response to the browser after specifice interval of time in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

> This is my sample code. I am able to do the functionality in my console but how can i send this piece of data into the browser. I need to show the data into my browser. How to do this

**This is my sample code. I am able to do the functionality in my console but how can i send this piece of data into the browser. I need to show the data into my browser. How to do this **

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var http = require('http');

var options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3030,
    path: '/'
  };

function between(minTemp, maxTemp, minHr, maxHr, minspo2, maxspo2) {  
    let i = 0;
    var tempArr = [];
    var hrArr = [];
    var spo2Arr = [];
    var dataArr = [];

    for(i=0 ; i<=5; i++){
        randomTempFloot= Math.random() * (maxTemp - minTemp) + minTemp
        randomTempInt = Math.round(randomTempFloot);


        randomHrFloot= Math.random() * (maxHr - minHr) + minHr
        randomHrInt = Math.round(randomHrFloot);



        randomSpo2Floot= Math.random() * (maxspo2 - minspo2) + minspo2
        randomSpo2Int = Math.round(randomSpo2Floot);

        tempArr.push(randomTempInt);
        hrArr.push(randomHrInt);
        spo2Arr.push(randomSpo2Int);
    }



    dataArr.push(tempArr,hrArr,spo2Arr);
    //JSON.stringify(dataArr)
    console.log(dataArr);
    return dataArr;

    }

    //setInterval(between,20000,97,103, 80,450, 70,100)

    //let res = between(97,103);

    request = function(req,res){
        http.get(options,function(res){
            res.on(between(97,103, 80,450, 70,100), function(data){
                console.log(data)

            })
        })
    }
    setInterval(request,2000);

    /*app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
        //sestInterval(between,2000,97,103, 80,450, 70,100);
        //app.setInterval(between,2000,97,103, 80,450, 70,100)
        res.json(between(97,103, 80,450, 70,100));
        //setInterval(between,2000,97,103, 80,450, 70,100);
        //res.send(sestInterval(between,2000,97,103, 80,450, 70,100));
   }
   );*/



app.listen(3030, () => {
 console.log("Server running on port 3030");
});
```

Comment: If anything do you need you can ask

Comment: It's is pointless to do waiting on the back-end. You can not control the speed of the internet connection from the client to your site. Send everything as fast as you can. If you still want some delay, do it from the browser by displaying information after a some time is passed.